# JQuery button even t issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery so I am slowly grasping everything. Been really stuck on this one thing.

**Goal**: I want to create an event where I click a button, it moves an element to the right. Then I click it again and it moves that element back to the left.

**Problem**: It works the first time, but if you click it again it just moves right again.

*Added my styles I was calling out*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = ".img";
    var slideBody = "#bodyWrapper";
    $(img).click(function () {
        if ($(slideBody).css("left", "0") <= "true") {
            $(slideBody).animate({
                left: "200px"
            }, 200);
        } else {
            $(slideBody).animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});

.img {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: yellow; 
opacity: 1;
left: 0px;
}
#bodyWrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `<= true`  Something is either true or false. There isn't anything in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the condition as:

```
    if ( $(slideBody).css("left") == 0 ){
        $( slideBody ).animate({left:"200px"}, 200);
    } else { 
        $( slideBody ).animate({ left:"0px" }, 200);
    }
```

Comment: I added it in and its registering as false. I added the styles I am using up above. Maybe that's causing an issue?

Comment: "0px" was the missing element! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to add a class to the element being moved left and/or right.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var img = ".img";
var slideBody = "#bodyWrapper"; 


$( img ).click(function() {

    if ( $(slideBody).is(".atLeft")){
            $( slideBody ).animate({left:"200px"}, 200);
            $( slideBody ).removeClass('atLeft');
    } else { 
            $( slideBody ).animate({ left:"0px" }, 200);
            $( slideBody ).addClass('atLeft');
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Why is it "better" to add a class in this case?

Comment: It definitely works, but was seeing if I could avoid adding another class to the mix. Good suggestion though!